# How to properly format equation symbols

Tags: equations, ieeetran, stacking-symbols

While writing a couple of equations, I stumbled upon a problem of poor spacing.
Example in question:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
\label{eq:48}
\hat{\mathcal{H}}_{rr}=B^{(e)}\hat{J}^{2}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, there isn't much harmony between the hat and the square of J. Same is appliable to the l.h.s..

Any suggestions regarding how to properly formatting such equations is dearly welcome!

Best,

Strelok

Comment: Hi, you can add easily `\,` into `{\,2}`.

Comment: Hi. I am unable to reproduce the screenshot you posted using  only the code you posted. It would appear that you're loading one or more font-related packages. Please do reveal which ones they may be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can reproduce your picture with

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\hat{\mathcal{H}}_{rr}=B^{(e)}\hat{J}^{2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The problem is in `mathptmx`, which is a poor 30 year old hack for getting Times in math papers.

Use a more modern package.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{calrsfs}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\hat{\mathcal{H}}_{rr}=B^{(e)}\hat{J}^{2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `rsfso` instead of `calrsfs`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{rsfso}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\hat{\mathcal{H}}_{rr}=B^{(e)}\hat{J}^{\,2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A worthwhile alternative to the `calrsfs` and `mathrsfs.sty` packages, which were last updated in 1994 and 1996, respectively, may be the `rsfso` package, last updated by Michael Sharpe in 2013. The latter uses the `rsfso` math font and provides an easy scaling option, whereas the former two use the `rsfs` math font (and don't provide a straightforward way to perform scaling). `rsfso` is much less heavily sloped (slantend?) than `rsfs`. In fact, I'd say the slant angle of `rsfso` is roughly the same as that of `newtxmath`. IMNSHO, the slant angle of `rsfs` verges on the bizarre...

Comment: @Mico Added the example with `rsfso`

Answer (score 5):

Add some kerning before the exponent. Also, for capital letters, I would use the `\widehat` command from `mathabx`. As it is already defined in `amssymb`, I defined a `\varwidehat` accent borrowed from mathabx:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{ieeetrantools}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10>
      <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88>
      mathx10
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\varwidehat}{0}{mathx}{"70}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  \label{eq:48}
  \varwidehat{\mathcal{H}}_{rr}=B^{(e)}\varwidehat{J}^{\mkern2mu 2}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I vote always too your answers. You are excellent user as also a Mathematician. Also I'm a Mathematician.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Thanks for your kind appreciation :o) I've seen you're Italian. May I know from which region?