# Latex \left(\right) curious effect in IEEEeqnarray environment

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment

I've written the following equation in a text, and something wierd happened to the height of the [] - they're not homogeneous as one would expect! The code is depicted below

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
    \label{eq:95}
\left[{\Gamma_{(J)}}^{2}\right]_{sym}&=& \Sigma _{g}^{+} + \Delta_{g} \nonumber \\
\left[{\Gamma_{(J)}}^{4}\right]_{sym}&=& \Sigma _{g}^{+} + \Delta_{g} + \Gamma_{g} \nonumber \\
\left[{\Gamma_{(J)}}^{6}\right]_{sym}&=& \Sigma _{g}^{+} + \Delta_{g} + \Gamma_{g} + I_{g}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

The result of this code is the following:

[image]

Notice the weird height of the [ ] ? Any suggestions/advices on how to overcome this issue will be welcome!

Comment: Using the `IEEEtran` class on CTAN, instead of the `amsart` class plus `IEEEtran` package, I cannot recreate your problem.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I think the package is called `IEEEtrantools`, but even with that I can't reproduce the problem either.

Comment: I've already advised you that `mathptmx` is the wrong package to use: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400359/4427

Comment: Please fix your example so that it produces the image shown.

Comment: @egreg , the wierd thing is that I don't seem to have mathptmx loaded! Can it load by default?

Comment: @Strelok Please, show the real premble you have

Comment: @egreg, since it was too big for the textbox, I placed it on PasteBin

https://pastebin.com/X35Z4a6X

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Strelok That's not the preamble (but it's useful as well): what do you have from `\documentclass` up to `\begin{document}`?

Comment: @egreg Hmm... I digged through and I believe I found out what you wanted!

https://pastebin.com/CBgfTBFz

Comment: @Strelok I guess that the `times` option to `\documentclass` is the culprit.

Comment: @egreg , and you guessed correctly. Problem solved. Kudos and many thanks to you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68520/discussion-between-strelok-and-egreg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package is called `IEEEtrantools`; but the issue can only be reproduced with `mathptmx` loaded, that's not really good for serious typesetting.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
    \label{eq:95}
\left[{\Gamma_{(J)}}^{2}\right]_{sym}&=& \Sigma _{g}^{+} + \Delta_{g} \nonumber \\
\left[{\Gamma_{(J)}}^{4}\right]_{sym}&=& \Sigma _{g}^{+} + \Delta_{g} + \Gamma_{g} \nonumber \\
\left[{\Gamma_{(J)}}^{6}\right]_{sym}&=& \Sigma _{g}^{+} + \Delta_{g} + \Gamma_{g} + I_{g} \nonumber \\
\left[{\Gamma_{(J)}}^{\smash{6}\vphantom{2}}\right]_{sym}&=& \Sigma _{g}^{+} + \Delta_{g} + \Gamma_{g} + I_{g}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

6: \sbox0{$\scriptstyle6$}\the\ht0

2: \sbox0{$\scriptstyle2$}\the\ht0

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see from the last two lines, the 6 is 0.13pt higher than the 2, thus triggering the next size.

You should not use `\left` and `\right` here, but if you want, the workaround is typing `\smash{6}\vphantom{2}` that hides the height of 6, replacing it with the height of 2.

With `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` the problem does not arise.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
    \label{eq:95}
\left[{\Gamma_{(J)}}^{2}\right]_{sym}&=& \Sigma _{g}^{+} + \Delta_{g} \nonumber \\
\left[{\Gamma_{(J)}}^{4}\right]_{sym}&=& \Sigma _{g}^{+} + \Delta_{g} + \Gamma_{g} \nonumber \\
\left[{\Gamma_{(J)}}^{6}\right]_{sym}&=& \Sigma _{g}^{+} + \Delta_{g} + \Gamma_{g} + I_{g}        
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `\left` and `\right`, and also with `align` instead of `IEEEeqnarray`:

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
[{\Gamma_{(J)}}^{2}]_{sym}&= \Sigma _{g}^{+} + \Delta_{g} \nonumber \\
[{\Gamma_{(J)}}^{4}]_{sym}&= \Sigma _{g}^{+} + \Delta_{g} + \Gamma_{g} \nonumber \\
[{\Gamma_{(J)}}^{6}]_{sym}&= \Sigma _{g}^{+} + \Delta_{g} + \Gamma_{g} + I_{g}
\label{eq:95}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]